# How to deploy a Force ID app when all objects are referencing each other

Tags: salesforce, force-ide

When I try to deploy my app, it fail due to a conflict.

I have 3 items:

1. A visualforce page
2. An apex class
3. A custom object

The custom object overides the new button to the visualforce page. Hence when I try to safe it, there is a conflict and it fails.

The visualforce page references the apex class. Hence when I try to safe it first, it fails.

The apex class references the custom object. Hence when I try to save it first, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

CHicken and egg problem. You have a circular dependency :) Unfortunately Salesforce is quite smart at resolving them but fails in such scenarios.

You'll need 2 separate deployments and you can do it in 2 ways (at least I think they're simplest).

**Option 1**

Comment out whole body of the VF "new" page and the reference to controller extension. Leave an empty shell:

```
<apex:page standardController="CustomObject__c">
</apex:page>
```

This will still be a valid "new" page override (although a weird one) and you'll be able to deploy.

1. Deploy object, class and this stub page.
2. Deploy the page (or edit it directly because we can edit VF on production).

**Option 2**

Remove the "new" override, deploy all (it will be a normal VF page), change manually the object's properties (or deploy the object again). This is a simpler scenario, harder to make mistakes because you don't really edit code on live environment.

You can use similar tricks if you need to deploy a VF page embedded in page layout.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a problem if you deploy all the related objects together, instead of one at a time. The Force.com IDE can deploy many files at once.

I have used this method for deploying much code that has custom objects with apex page overrides and controllers like you have mentioned.