# How to Deploy an existing project in Force.com

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i am using eclipse IDE i am provided with an src folder which contains code i have to save this code into my development org.
How i am trying to approach this 
1.first i created a Force.com project
2.then i  copy given src(Ctrl+c) folder and paste(Ctrl+v) in to my project in eclipse
3. i added metadata components by right clicking on project
Force.com >Add/remove metadata components

4.then i right click on my project 
Force.com >Deploy to server

i am getting failure error

## Deploy Results:

File Name:    applications/Rule.app
   Full Name:  Rule
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: In field: tab - no CustomTab named Rule__c found

File Name:    objects/RuleAction_*c.object
   Full Name:  RuleAction*_c
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: manageruleactions does not exist or is not a valid override for action Edit.

File Name:    pages/ManageRuleActions.page
   Full Name:  ManageRuleActions
   Action:  NO ACTION
   Result:  FAILED
   Problem: Invalid field Notify_User_*c for SObject RuleAction*_c

can any one please tell a suitable path how to save the whole src folder code in development org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say exact steps. You'll have to keep trying while resolving the dependencies. [How to deploy a Force ID app when all objects are referencing each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919942/how-to-deploy-a-force-id-app-when-all-objects-are-referencing-each-other) is a question about similar problem.

First one should be fairly simple. You might have `applications/Rule.app` but looks like you're missing `tabs/Rule__c.tab`. Easiest would be to go to your target environment and use Setup -> Create -> Tabs to create the tab for this object. Then the app deployment should work and if you want - you can download the tab definition file later.

Next two - try to initiate a deployment that would push both `objects/RuleAction__c.object` and `pages/ManageRuleActions.page` at the same time. If it still doesn't work - split your actions like in my answer to this similar question (temporarily comment out the body of VF page or remove the edit action override definition from the object file).