# Rule__c : managerules does not exist or is not a valid override for action Edit.

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i have a class in dev org with code is

name of class is ManageRules.cls

```
/**
* This class is used for creating and editing Rule
**/
public with sharing class ManageRules{
public Rule__c newrule {get;set;}
public String objType {get;set;}
public string SearchEvalRule {get;set;}
public string Descr {get;set;}
public List<SelectOption> objOptions {get;set;}
// public String descr {get;set;}
public boolean edit {get;set;}
String ruleId;

public ManageRules(Apexpages.StandardController stdcon){
ruleId = stdcon.getId();
newrule = new Rule__c();
objOptions = new List<SelectOption>();

edit=false;
/**
* Add standard Objects
*/
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('',''));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Account','Account'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Contact','Contact'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Opportunity','Opportunity'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Case','Case'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Lead','Lead'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Campaign','Campaign'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Quote','Quote'));
objOptions.add(new SelectOption('Product2','Product'));
//objOptions.add(new SelectOption('ForeCast','Forecast'));

Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> mapObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(String objname:mapObj.keySet()){
Schema.SObjectType sobj = mapObj.get(objname);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult descRes = sobj.getDescribe();
/**
* Add custom objects
*/
if(descRes.isCustom() && !descRes.isCustomSetting()){
String objLabel = descRes.getLabel();
objOptions.add(new SelectOption(objName,objLabel));
}
}

/* Edit Rule */
if(ruleId!=null){
edit=true;
newrule = [select name,object__c,Rule_Execution_Plan__c,Available__c,Evaluation_Rule__c,Description__c from rule__c where id=:ruleId];
if(newrule!=null){
objtype=newrule.object__c;
Descr =newrule.Description__c;
SearchEvalRule =newrule.Evaluation_Rule__c ;

}
}

}

Public List<SelectOption> getEvalRule() {

List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -'));
Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Rule__c.Evaluation_Rule__c.getDescribe();
for (Schema.Picklistentry picklistEntry : field.getPicklistValues())
{
options.add(new SelectOption(pickListEntry.getValue(),pickListEntry.getLabel()));
}
return options;
}
public PageReference saveRule(){
newrule.object__c = objtype;
newrule.Evaluation_Rule__c=SearchEvalRule;
newrule.Description__c= Descr;

try{
Database.upsert(newrule);
return(new PageReference('/'+newrule.id));
}
catch(Exception e){
ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,e.getDMLMessage(0));
ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
return null;
}

}

public PageReference saveAndNewRule(){
newrule.object__c = objtype;
newrule.Evaluation_Rule__c=SearchEvalRule;
newrule.Description__c= Descr;
edit=false;
try{
Database.upsert(newrule);
newrule = new Rule__c();
return(new PageReference('/apex/manageRules'));
}
catch(Exception e){
ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.Error,e.getDMLMessage(0));
ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
return null;
}

}


}
```

i created an object its giving me error

Description Resource Path Location Type
Save error: Rule_*c : managerules does not exist or is not a valid override for action Edit. Rule*_c.object /RuleCriteria/src/objects line 0 Force.com save problem

my Rule__c object code segment where i am getting this error is :

```
<actionOverrides>
<actionName>Edit</actionName>
<content>ManageRules</content>
<skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
<type>Visualforce</type>
</actionOverrides>
```

i am unable to figure why its showing me this error its an existing project so i have to deploy it on my dev org .on others org its working perfectly fine.i first save this class code and then try to save this object code and getting this error.can any one please how to resolve this issue??

Comment: I told you already in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14299386/313628 (last paragraph) ;) One method would be to deploy `ManageRules.page` (can be blank: `<apex:page standardController="Rule__c"></apex:page>`), then the object, class and finally proper version of the page again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Deploy an existing project in Force.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297158/how-to-deploy-an-existing-project-in-force-com)

Comment: sorry didn't notice the second part of your answer!!